# Calendar's getTime() method gives back wrong hours

Tags: java, android

Well i would like to simply get the current date in my app.

I use this snippet:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.getTime().toGMTString();
```

for some reason it gives me like:
"22 Feb 2013 18:00:48 GMT"

Well it is **19:00 right now in Hungary**, **not 18:00**, 
There is **1 hour difference.**

What the heck ? :)
How can i implement a reliable way to always get the current date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replies, i shouldnt use GMT.
Instead of that:

```
 cal.getTime().toLocaleString();
```

Comment: `toLocaleString` is also deprecated. Use a date format as advised:`String s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(cal.getTime());`

Comment: Please note that almost all the methods of the `Date` class has been deprecated. It is usually not preferable to use those methods unless there are VERY specific reasons why you would have to use them.

Comment: Well okay, i try it:
String s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(cal.getTime());

Answer (score 3):

Well, Hungary is GMT+1, that's where the missing hour went. The [`toGMTString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toGMTString%28%29) is deprecated, and you should instead use the [`DateFormat.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29)-method.